# Why can't I make a vector of references?

Tags: c++, reference, stl, stdvector, container-data-type

When I do this:

```
std::vector<int> hello;
```

Everything works great. However, when I make it a vector of references instead:

```
std::vector<int &> hello;
```

I get horrible errors like

> error C2528: 'pointer' : pointer to reference is illegal

I want to put a bunch of references to structs into a vector, so that I don't have to meddle with pointers. Why is vector throwing a tantrum about this? Is my only option to use a vector of pointers instead?

Comment: you can use std::vector<reference_wrapper<int> > hello; See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=217

Comment: @amit the link is valid no longer, official documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Answer (score 430):

The component type of containers like vectors must be [*assignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable). References are not assignable (you can only initialize them once when they are declared, and you cannot make them reference something else later). Other non-assignable types are also not allowed as components of containers, e.g. `vector<const int>` is not allowed.

Comment: Are you saying I can't have a vector of vectors?  (I'm sure I've done that...)

Comment: Yes, a std::vector< std::vector<int> > is correct,  std::vector is assignable.

Comment: Indeed, this is the "actual" reason. The error about T* being impossible of T is U& is just a side-effect of the violated requirement that T must be assignable. If vector was able to precisely check the type parameter, then it would probably say "violated requirement: T& not assignable"

Comment: Checking the assignable concept at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/Assignable.html all operations except the swap are valid on references.

Comment: I think the component type must also be default-constructible, no?  And references are not that either.

Comment: @cdhowie, no, the component type need not be default-constructible, as long as you don't call resize() or the vector constructor that takes a size.  (I conclude this from trying it using g++, not from reading any spec)

Comment: I had this issue trying to do:
`vector<vector <int>&>`

The solution was to work with:
`vector<vector<int>*>`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I guess it could do like `static_assert<std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_reference<T>>>` or something along those lines

Comment: This is no longer true. Since C++11, the only operation-independent requirement for element is to be "Erasable", and reference is not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144419/stl-container-of-references-c11.

Comment: `References are not assignable (you can only initialize them once when they are declared, and you cannot make them reference something else later).` Then why can I `for (item& i: myVector) i = foo;` ? I am assigning the reference to something else.

Comment: @johnbakers: You are modifying the thing the reference points to, not the reference itself. Modifying the reference itself would allow you to have the reference to point to something else, which is impossible with C++ references.

Comment: It could, of course, be a specialization that internally stores pointers and presents them as references in the public API. That's what `reference_wrapper` does.

Answer (score 157):

yes you can, look for [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), that mimics a reference but is assignable and also can be "reseated"

Comment: Is there a way of getting around calling `get()` first when trying to access a method of an instance of a class in this wrapper? E.g. `reference_wrapper<MyClass> my_ref(...); my_ref.get().doStuff();` is not very reference like.

Comment: Isn't it implcitly castable to the Type itself by returning the reference?

Comment: Yes, but that requires a context that implies which conversion is required. Member access does not do that, hence the need for `.get()`. What *timdiels* wants is `operator.`; have a look at the latest proposals/discussions about that.

Comment: Note however that while `reference_wrapper` unlike the raw reference type can be "reseated", it still cannot be uninitialized, so it is not default constructible. That means that while one can construct `vector<reference_wrapper<int>>{int1, int2, int3}`, one still cannot have a vector with with default constructed elements: `vector<reference_wrapper<int>>(5)`. This isn't even caught by IDE (CLion), but fails compilation.

Comment: I find it odd that this is declared in `<functional>` -- it seems more general than merely callable objects.

Answer (score 43):

By their very nature, references can only be set at the time they are created; i.e., the following two lines have very different effects:

```
int & A = B;   // makes A an alias for B
A = C;         // assigns value of C to B.
```

Futher, this is illegal:

```
int & D;       // must be set to a int variable.
```

However, when you create a vector, there is no way to assign values to it's items at creation.  You are essentially just making a whole bunch of the last example.

Comment: "when you create a vector, there is no way to assign values to it's items at creation" I don't understand what you mean by this statement. What are "its items at creation"? I can create an empty vector. And I can add items with .push_back(). You are just pointing out that references are not default-constructible. But I can definitely have vectors of classes that are not default-constructible.

Comment: The element ype of std::vector<T> is not required to be default constructible. You can write struct A { A(int); private: A(); }; vector<A> a; just fine - as long as you don't use such methods that require it to be default constructible (like v.resize(100); - but instead you will need to do v.resize(100, A(1)); )

Comment: And how would you write such a push_back() in this case?  It will still use assignment, not construction.

Comment: James Curran, No default construction takes place there. push_back just placement-news A into the preallocated buffer. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672352/how-is-dynamic-memory-managed-in-stdvector . Note that *my* claim is only that vector can handle non-default-constructible types. I don't claim, of course, that it could handle T& (it can't, of course).

Answer (score 37):

### TL; DR

Use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string hello = "Hello, ";
    std::string world = "everyone!";
    typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> vec_t;
    vec_t vec = {hello, world};
    vec[1].get() = "world!";
    std::cout << hello << world << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/921852b054e47dff)

### Long answer

As [standard suggests](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements), for a standard container `X` containing objects of type `T`, `T` must be `Erasable` from `X`.

`Erasable` means that the following expression is well formed:

```
allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)
```

`A` is container's allocator type, `m` is allocator instance and `p` is a pointer of type `*T`. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#general-15.6) for `Erasable` definition.

By default, `std::allocator<T>` is used as vector's allocator. With the default allocator, the requirement is equivalent to the validity of `p->~T()` (Note the `T` is a reference type and `p` is pointer to a reference). However, [pointer to a reference is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632762/why-are-pointers-to-a-reference-illegal-in-c), hence the expression is not well formed.

Answer (score 35):

Ion Todirel already mentioned an answer **YES** using `std::reference_wrapper`. **Since C++11** we have a mechanism to retrieve object from `std::vector` and remove the reference by using `std::remove_reference`. Below is given an example compiled using `g++` and `clang` with option `-std=c++11` and executed successfully.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <functional>
    
    class MyClass {
    public:
        void func() {
            std::cout << "I am func \n";
        }

        MyClass(int y) : x(y) {}

        int getval() {
            return x;
        }

    private: 
        int x;
    };

    int main() {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>> vec;

        MyClass obj1(2);
        MyClass obj2(3);

        MyClass& obj_ref1 = std::ref(obj1);
        MyClass& obj_ref2 = obj2;

        vec.push_back(obj_ref1);
        vec.push_back(obj_ref2);

        for (auto obj3 : vec) {
            std::remove_reference<MyClass&>::type(obj3).func();      
            std::cout << std::remove_reference<MyClass&>::type(obj3).getval() << "\n";
        }             
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see the value in `std::remove_reference<>` here. The point of `std::remove_reference<>` is to allow you to write "the type T, but without being a reference if it is one". So `std::remove_reference<MyClass&>::type` is just the same as writing `MyClass`.

Comment: No value at all in that - you can just write **`for (MyClass obj3 : vec)
        std::cout << obj3.getval() << "\n";`**  (or `for (const MyClass& obj3: vec)` if you declare `getval()` const, as you should).

Answer (score 20):

It's a flaw in the C++ language.  You can't take the address of a reference, since attempting to do so would result in the address of the object being referred to, and thus you can never get a pointer to a reference.  `std::vector` works with pointers to its elements, so the values being stored need to be able to be pointed to.  You'll have to use pointers instead.

Comment: I guess it could be implemented using a void * buffer and placement new. Not that this would make much sense.

Comment: "Flaw in the language" is too strong. It is by design. I don't think it is required that vector works with pointers to elements. However it is required that the element be assignable. References are not.

Comment: You can't take the `sizeof` a reference either.

Comment: you don't need a pointer to a reference, you have the reference, if you do need the pointer, just keep the pointer itself; there is no problem to be solved here

Comment: It could, of course, be a specialization that internally stores pointers and presents them as references in the public API. That's what `reference_wrapper` does.

Answer (score 15):

[`boost::ptr_vector<int>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) will work.

**Edit:** was a suggestion to use `std::vector< boost::ref<int> >`, which will not work because you can't default-construct a `boost::ref`.

Comment: But you can have a vector or non default-constructible types, right? You only have to be careful not to use the default ctor. of the vector

Comment: @Manuel: Or `resize`.

Comment: Be careful, Boost's pointer containers take exclusive ownership of the pointees. [Quote](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html#motivation): "When you do need shared semantics, this library is not what you need."

Answer (score 3):

As other have mentioned, you will probably end up using a vector of pointers instead.

However, you may want to consider using a [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead!

Comment: This answer is not workable, since a ptr_vector is supposed to be a storage. That is it will delete the pointers at removal. So it is not usable for his purpose.

Comment: One way or another you have to store something somewhere! Docs: "Instances of std::reference_wrapper are objects (they can be copied or stored in containers)"

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason in C++14, "International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) Programming Language C++"

[8.3.2-5.s1]
There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason why you couldn't have a vector of references, it's just not a part of the API, presumably to keep it similar to an array. A specialization could easily be added that works with references, stores them as pointers internally and presents as references in the API:

```cpp
vector<int&> ivref;
int i = 42;
ivref.push_back(i); // address of i is stored
ivref.front() = 43; // i is set to 43
ivref.push_back(44); // Marked deleted for rvalue references 
ivref.resize(10);    // Marked deleted for vector of references
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other comments suggest, you are confined to using pointers.
But if it helps, here is one technique to avoid facing directly with pointers.

You can do something like the following:

```
vector<int*> iarray;
int default_item = 0; // for handling out-of-range exception

int& get_item_as_ref(unsigned int idx) {
   // handling out-of-range exception
   if(idx >= iarray.size()) 
      return default_item;
   return reinterpret_cast<int&>(*iarray[idx]);
}
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not needed

Comment: As the other answers show, we are not confined to using pointers at all.