# A struct is not updating one of its member variables in c++

Tags: c++

I have a struct Creature and a struct Game. Game is a "friend" of Creature.
In game I have
vector creatures;
and I add a creature x to that vector thourgh a function called addC

```
void addc (Creature& c){
    creatures.push_back(c);
}
```

Now I'm in another function "foo" that is a public method of the struct Game.

```
void foo (Creature& c){
    ...
}
```

In that function I need to find another creature from the vector creatures that
matches some information from Creature c.
So I made another public method in Game called fooHelper

```
void fooHelper (char s, int x, int y){
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < creatures.size() && (!found); ++i){
        Creature& c = creatures[i];
        if (x == c.x && y == c.y){
            c.s = s;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

however when I check if the second creature's "s" member is being updated, it turns out that
it is not!  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since I'm pushing by references to the vector.
and I'm getting the creature by reference from the vector.

the vector in game looks like this

```
struct Game{
    private:
        vector<Creature> creatures;
    ...
}

struct Creature{
    private:
        char s;
        int x; int y;
    ...
}
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
creatures.push_back(c);
```

Stores a *copy* of `c` into your vector: standard containers have *value semantics*. If you need reference semantics, you should store pointers into your vector.

Usually it is a good idea to use *smart pointers*, and which one to use depends on the ownership policy of your application. In this case, based on the information I could get from your question's text, it seems reasonable to let `Game` be the unique owner of all `Creature`s in the game (and therefore the only object which is *responsible* for the lifetime of the owned `Creature`s, and in particular for destroying them when they won't be needed anymore), so `std::unique_ptr` should be a good choice:

```
#include <memory> // For std::unique_ptr

struct Game{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Creature>> creatures;
    ...
};
```

Your member function `addc()` would then become:

```
void addc(std::unique_ptr<Creature> c)
{
    creatures.push_back(std::move(c));
}
```

And a client would invoke it this way:

```
Game g;
// ...
std::unique_ptr<Creature> c(new Creature());
g.addc(std::move(c));
```

Your `foohelper()` function, on the other hand, would be rewritten into something like this:

```
void fooHelper (char s, int x, int y) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < creatures.size() && (!found); ++i){
        std::unique_ptr<Creature>& c = creatures[i];
        if (x == c->x && y == c->y) {
            c->s = s;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, your class `Game` could return *non-owning* raw pointers (or references) to clients requiring access to the stored creatures.

Answer (score 1):

When you push your creature reference into the vector, it's making a copy. It's a vector of type "Creature", and so it's making a copy from the reference that you give it. One solution would be to keep a vector of creature pointers.

edit - this question helps explain things a little better than I was able to on why you can't have a vector of references: [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)