# How to create a collection of stream objects

Tags: c++, iostream

As most know it's not possible to have a [standard collection of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references). It's also not possible to copy a stream object.

But what if I want to make a collection (say a `std::vector`) of stream objects or stream object references?

I know I can wrap the stream object reference in e.g. a structure, but then you either need to implement the complete interface (if you want to use the wrapper directly as a stream, which I would prefer), or use a public getter function and use that everywhere to get the actual stream.

Is there a simpler way? C++11 solutions are okay.

Comment: Why not use a collection of pointers?

Comment: Or a collection of smart pointers if its necessary to destroy them automatically?

Comment: What about a collection of `std::reference_wrapper<TheStreamType>`?

Comment: @riv It would of course work, but I would rather not unless there is no other way.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you hit the nail right on target with that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a container of references, but you can have a container of [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). Perhaps you want something like:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<stream_type>> v;
```

You can treat a `std::reference_wrapper` very much like a reference (in fact, it is implicitly convertible to a reference type), but it has the extra advantage of being an object type.

Comment: Just tested and it works fine. Still have to use the `get` function to get the referenced stream if used directly in e.g. output or input operations, but not when passing to other functions. I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-copyable objects in collections:

```
// this uses move constructors
std::vector<std::fstream> v {std::fstream{"file1.txt"}, std::fstream{"file2.txt"}};

// this doesn't require the type to even be movable
v.emplace_back("file3.txt");
```

Although avoiding pointer and reference-like types this way will only work if you don't need to use streams as polymorphic objects.