# If I want to pass constant values to vector<~>, what should I write?

Tags: c++

I've been reading Accelerated C++ 2000 for a few days now, and I came upon the vector<~>.

Suppose I want to append values to my vector that must never change, should I write

```
const vector<double>;
```

or

```
vector<const double>;
```

?

I'm asking because I'm not sure which one will work according to what I want to happen.

Comment: Note that you cannot delete elements from a vector of const elements, because deleting the element at index i requires assigning to all elements at index >= i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. The component type of vectors must be asssignable. That means you cannot append to vector values that cannot be changed. [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references/922455#922455)

All you can to is to make vector const:

```
const vector<double>;
```

But this means that the vector cannot be changed. You cannot add to it nor change its elements.

Comment: Just a clarification. We're allowed to prepend a **const** inside the angle brackets because C++ syntax dictates that the data type of the contents vector<~> has should be declared inside the angle brackets? By that, I mean it's not the usual "dataType name" declaration.

Comment: @solitude Yes. Google "C++ templates".

Comment: Yes, in this case the data type is `const double`

Comment: `vector<const double>` won't compile for me. Should it? I get what I call "template vomit."

Comment: @FredLarson What does a "template vomit" mean?

Comment: @solitude: It's my own term for the frightening cascade of error messages you get from errors using templates.