# When a lvalue is passed to T&&, what will happen?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, rvalue-reference

Here is an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th Edition*:

> Exercise 16.45: Given the following template, explain what happens if
>   we call g on a literal value such as 42. What if we call g on a
>   variable of type int?  P.690

```
template <typename T>
void g(T&& val)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
}

int main()
{
    //g(42);

    int i;
    g(i);
}
```

When calling on `42` , it compiled.

When on `i`, the compiler complained a lot of errors, part of which is pasted as below.

```
forming pointer to reference type 'int&'
```

My questions are

1. When calling on literal value ,`42` in this case, what type was deduced for `T`?
2. when on `i`, why didn't it compile? How to understand these error messages?

Comment: I suggest the reading of [Universal References in C++11](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html

The first of the remaining two rules for rvalue references affects old-style lvalue references as well. Recall that in pre-11 C++, it was not allowed to take a reference to a reference: something like A& & would cause a compile error. C++11, by contrast, introduces the following reference collapsing rules:

```
A& & becomes A&
A& && becomes A&
A&& & becomes A&
A&& && becomes A&&
```

Secondly, there is a special template argument deduction rule for function templates that take an argument by rvalue reference to a template argument:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&&);
```

Here, the following apply:

- When foo is called on an lvalue of type A, then T resolves to A& and hence, by the reference collapsing rules above, the argument type effectively becomes A&.
- When foo is called on an rvalue of type A, then T resolves to A, and hence the argument type becomes A&&.

So case 1, when passing 42, you are calling g with a rvalue, so T is resolved to `int` thus g's parameter is `int&&` and std::vector is legal.

In case 2, when passing i, you are calling  g with a lvalue, so T is resolved to `int&` thus g's parameter is `int&` and `std::vector<int&>` is **NOT** legal.

Remove the line with the vector and it will work fine in both cases.

Comment: +1 for clear explanation.One more question, why is `std::vector<int&>` **NOT** legal?

Comment: Have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references