# vector<int &> not compiling

Tags: c++, vector, reference

The question comes from the code below:

```
vector<int &> one;  //compile failed
```

I am confused why the code does not compile.

Comment: You can't put references in containers. Use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: References are non-copyable and non-movable.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a vector of references directly.

However you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to achieve the result you seek.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When the IDE(VS2008) tells me the code compile failed, Then I know "I can't have a vector of references directly", which is your answer also. I want to know the  underlying reasons. Thank you.

Comment: Is "because the standard says so" good enough? "Containers are objects that store other objects." §23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]  References are not objects.

Comment: Thank you. But a pointer is not a object, too. Could you help me?

Comment: A pointer is, indeed, an object.  "An object is a
region of storage." §1.8 [intro.object].  References are not objects, therefore, because "[i]t is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage" §8.3.2 [dcl.ref].

Comment: You are so smart, and hank you for your patience. And I get it. Thank you again. In addition, Could you send me a c++ standard docs? or a internet link?

Comment: While the official, ISO standard documents require payment to access, N3337 (which was, I believe, the first draft released after C++11 was accepted, and has only very minor changes) can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: OK, I have download from the website you give me. Thank you. Your are so friendly and smart. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references) (I don't currently have the rep to flag it).

STL containers must hold types that are assignable, and references are not assignable.