# Copying elements of rapidjson::Value to std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, rapidjson

I need a function that returns all members of a `rapidjson::Value` as an `std::vector`. I am trying to avoid to write `if`s with `IsArray()` everytime I need. Unfortunately the following code does not work.

```
std::vector<const rapidjson::Value&> valueToList(const rapidjson::Value& value)
{
    std::vector<const rapidjson::Value&> valueList;

    if (value.IsArray())
    {
        for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < value.Size(); i++)
        {
            valueList.push_back(val[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        valueList.push_back(val);
    }

    return valueList;
}
```

I get the error **push_back is ambiguous**. Is there an easy way to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: You can't have a vector of native references. The second and third answers [**to this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references) do a decent job of explaining why and proffering alternatives (mores than the selected answer to that question, imho).

Answer (score 2):

The std::vector vector must be assignable, so you cannot have a std::vector of const references.  Instead, try storing either **rapidjson::Value**s or pointers to them.  If you really want to store references, check out **std::reference_wrapper**.

From section 23.2.4 Class template vector of the C++ standard:

> ...the stored object shall meet the requirements of Assignable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Store pointers to the `Value`s and you'll be fine. Make sure not to lose the `rapidjson::Document`.