# queue of Type& C++

Tags: c++, reference, queue

I had to use a fixed size queue, which is limited to 5 elements.
Here is a code, in which I tried to encapsulate the implementation.

```
typedef enum result{SUCCESS = 1,FAILURE = 0} Result;

class VehicleParcelQueue::public std::queue<Parcel&>{
    public:
        Result push_back(Parcel&){
            if (size() >= 5) return FAILURE;
            else{
                std::queue<Parcel&>::push_back(Parcel&);
                return SUCCESS;
            }
        }
    };
```

from some reason I'm getting the following error:

> error: forming pointer to reference type 'Parcel&'

(Parcel is a class I implemented elsewhere)

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

[edit: I looked in the suggested question, but if I change it to:

```
class VehicleParcelQueue::public std::queue<Parcel*>{
    public:
        Result push_back(Parcel*){
            if (size() >= 5) return FAILURE;
            else{
                std::queue<Parcel*>::push_back(Parcel*);
                return SUCCESS;
            }
        }
    };
```

I still get the same error.

Comment: [For the same reason as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/922360/440302), you can't create a queue of references.

Comment: You probably want to pass the parameter to `push_back` as `const Parcel&` and store it in a `std::queue<Parcel>`.

Comment: does the effect will be that queue will hold pointer to a copy of Parcel object or to the object Parcle& poins to?