# Difference between : list<object *> and list<object &>

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

if i have a class "Movie" as follows:(c++)

```
class Movie{
private:
    string name; 
    string year; 
    list<Employee ?> e;
}
```

what is the difference between :

```
list<Employee *> e  
list<Employee &> e
```

and how do i implement the destructor
~Movie() for each variation ?

Comment: This `list<Employee &> e  ` won't compile.

Comment: One compiles, one doesn't, and neither should actually be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an STL container of references to objects. That is,

```
std::list<Employee&> e;
```

doesn't have a chance to compile. This is attributed to the fact that STL containers require that their elements are [Erasable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable) [Note: Before C++11 the requirements were to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible)]. Unfortunately, references are not.

Also since you have the C++11 tag, you should be aware that use of raw pointers is highly discouraged in favour of smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Thus, is better to avoid this:

```
std::list<Employee*> e;
```

in favour of something like:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Employee>> e;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a list of references `list<Employee &> e` because the elements in the list have to be [Assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and a reference cannot be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments `list<Employee &> e` won't compile. If you want to do a reference to the class and not a pointer, you can use `list<std::reference_wrapper<Employee>> e`. The type has to be [Assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references).