# Computing the type of a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, dependent-name

Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    typedef M< &T::foo > MT;
}
```

This would work for:

```
S<Widget> SW;
```

where `Widget::foo()` is some function

How would I modify the definition of `struct S` to allow the following instead:

```
S<Widget*> SWP;
```

Comment: Should it work for *only* pointers or for pointers and non-pointers alike?

Comment: Some things in the question are unclear: what is `M`? How is `Widget::foo` connected to the type that you instantiate? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ideally it should work for both pointers and non-pointers, however I would really even appreciate a version of the struct that worked with pointer types alone.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: What I am really trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688926/c-determine-the-class-of-a-pointer-type-in-the-use-of-boost-multiindex

Comment: What on earth is `&T::()`?

Comment: @T.C. : Typo, please see corrected version. Thanks

Comment: Now I don't understand what you're trying to do anymore at all. I thought you wanted a `typedef` to a *pointer to member [function]* of the type `S` is instantiated with. Is this so? How does this relate with your other question? Can you maybe show how you *want to use* the construct?

Comment: When asked what you want to do, you link to another question, where there has been a request for clarification that is 5 hours old left unsatisfied.  So is what you want to do is "ask unclear questions and refuse to clarify"?

Comment: @5gon12eder: The example in the link below may be clearer. Instead of "employee" I want to use some type T which may be a pointer to some other class. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#const_mem_fun

Comment: So the Boost example should also work with a container of `employee *`s? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Yakk: Fair point. I was trying to distill my original request down to something much simpler here.

Comment: @5gon12eder : Yes. However, I want to say multi_index_container< T, ... > ... if T is a de-referenceable type then I want to compute the type of *T to describe &(<type of *T>)::foo

Comment: Thanks, I got it now; currently working on an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the following type transformation.

- given `T`, return `T`
- given `T *`, return `T`

It so happens that the standard library already has implemented this for us  in [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) (though it's not hard to do yourself).

With this, you can then write

```
using object_type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
using return_type = /* whatever foo returns */;
using MT = M<object_type, return_type, &object_type::foo>;
```

Regarding your comment that you also want to work with smart pointers, we have to re-define the type transformation.

- given a smart pointer type `smart_ptr<T>`, return `smart_ptr<T>::element_type`, which should be `T`
- given a pointer type `T *`, return `T`
- otherwise, given `T`, return `T` itself

For this, we'll have to code our own meta-function. At least, I'm not aware of anything in the standard library that would help here.

We start by defining the primary `template` (the “otherwise” case).

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct unwrap_obect_type { using type = T; };
```

The second (anonymous) type parameter that is defaulted to `void` will be of use later.

For (raw) pointers, we provide the following partial specialization.

```
template <typename T>
struct unwrap_obect_type<T *, void> { using type = T; };
```

If we'd stop here, we'd basically get `std::remove_pointer`. But we'll add an additional partial specialization for smart pointers. Of course, we'll first have to define what a “smart pointer” is. For the purpose of this example, we'll treat every type with a nested `typedef` named `element_type` as a smart pointer. Adjust this definition as you see fit.

```
template <typename T>
struct unwrap_obect_type
<
  T,
  std::conditional_t<false, typename T::element_type, void>
>
{
  using type = typename T::element_type;
};
```

The second type parameter `std::conditional_t<false, typename T::element_type, void>` is a convoluted way to simulate [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) in C++14. The idea is that we have the following partial type function.

- given a type `T` with a nested `typedef` named `element_type`, return `void`
- otherwise, trigger a substitution failure

Therefore, if we are dealing with a smart pointer, we'll get a better match than the primary `template` and otherwise, SFINAE will remove this partial specialization from further consideration.

Here is a working example. [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) has suggested using [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) to invoke the member function. This makes the code a lot cleaner than my initial example.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename ObjT, typename RetT, RetT (ObjT::*Pmf)() const noexcept>
struct M
{
  template <typename ThingT>
  static RetT
  call(ThingT&& thing) noexcept
  {
    auto wrapper = std::mem_fn(Pmf);
    return wrapper(std::forward<ThingT>(thing));
  }
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct unwrap_obect_type { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct unwrap_obect_type<T *, void> { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct unwrap_obect_type<T, std::conditional_t<false, typename T::element_type, void>> { using type = typename T::element_type; };

template <typename T>
struct S
{

  template <typename ThingT>
  void
  operator()(ThingT&& thing) const noexcept
  {
    using object_type = typename unwrap_obect_type<T>::type;
    using id_caller_type          = M<object_type, int,                &object_type::id>;
    using name_caller_type        = M<object_type, const std::string&, &object_type::name>;
    using name_length_caller_type = M<object_type, std::size_t,        &object_type::name_length>;
    std::cout << "id:          " << id_caller_type::call(thing)          << "\n";
    std::cout << "name:        " << name_caller_type::call(thing)        << "\n";
    std::cout << "name_length: " << name_length_caller_type::call(thing) << "\n";
  }

};

class employee final
{

 private:

  int id_ {};
  std::string name_ {};

 public:

  employee(int id, std::string name) : id_ {id}, name_ {std::move(name)}
  {
  }

  int                  id()          const noexcept { return this->id_; }
  const std::string&   name()        const noexcept { return this->name_; }
  std::size_t          name_length() const noexcept { return this->name_.length(); }

};

int
main()
{
  const auto bob = std::make_shared<employee>(100, "Smart Bob");
  const auto s_object = S<employee> {};
  const auto s_pointer = S<employee *> {};
  const auto s_smart_pointer = S<std::shared_ptr<employee>> {};
  s_object(*bob);
  std::cout << "\n";
  s_pointer(bob.get());
  std::cout << "\n";
  s_smart_pointer(bob);
}
```

Comment: "Note that in order to actually invoke the member function, I had to introduce the helper that conditionally dereferences the pointer." We have `INVOKE` for that.

Comment: @T.C. Well, we *will* have… But even then, will `std::invoke` automagically call `(o.*pmf)()` or `(p->*pmf)()` depending on whether the callable is a pointer?

Comment: We have it already (via `mem_fn`). And yes, it will handle dereferencing (it does `((*p).*pmf)()` so that it even works with smart pointers and isn't confused by `->*` overloads). Also, the callable here is the PMF, not the object/pointer.

Comment: @5gon12eder thanks! I did see std:remove_pointer when I tried to solve this myself, however, I was under the impression that it does not work with smart pointer types. Is this true?

Comment: @T.C. I didn't know that this works / exists. I find it pretty awesome, thanks! I have updated the code. Of course you are also right that the callable is not the (pointer to the) object here.

Comment: @unshul It doesn't work with smart pointers and you didn't mention smart pointers in your OP. I'm also not sure you really want this because if you have a container of smart pointers, wouldn't it be more useful to invoke member functions (like `get`) on the smart pointers themselves?  Anyway, I have updated the answer to account for smart pointers as well.

Comment: @5gon12eder I wanted to make this collection as close to STL containers as possible. Just as we can declare std::vector<Widget> or std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>>, I would like to do the same with my collection. Thanks for your effort in answering my question.