# C++ Storing and passing references instead of values in an unordered_list

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, unordered-map

I have some code which compiles and runs fine, but passes the objects by value:

```
AssetRepository AssetRepositoryFactory::getAssetRepository(std::string clientId)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, AssetRepository>::iterator iterator = m_repositories.find(clientId);
    if ( iterator != m_repositories.end())
    {
        return iterator->second;
    }
    else
    {
        AssetRepository repository = AssetRepository(clientId);
        std::pair<std::string, AssetRepository> pair (clientId, repository);
        m_repositories.insert(pair);
        return repository;
    }

}
```

What I intended this code to do was pass by reference, but this is probably a fairly common newbie C++ developer mistake. So I tried to pass by reference by changing to this code:

```
AssetRepository& AssetRepositoryFactory::getAssetRepository(std::string clientId)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, AssetRepository&>::iterator iterator = m_repositories.find(clientId);
    if ( iterator != m_repositories.end())
    {
        return iterator->second;
    }
    else
    {
        AssetRepository repository = AssetRepository(clientId);
        std::pair<std::string, AssetRepository&> pair (clientId, repository);
        m_repositories.insert(pair);
        return repository;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
HEAP[CGF_flight_controller.exe]: Invalid allocation size - c3d9e9e0 (exceeded fffdefff)
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD24B3DD in CGF_flight_controller.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000000002C6F4F0.
Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in CGF_flight_controller.exe.
```

That's if I call it via

```
AssetRepository repository = AssetRepositoryFactory::getInstance().getAssetRepository("clientId0");
```

Or, if I call

```
AssetRepository &repository = AssetRepositoryFactory::getInstance().getAssetRepository("clientId0");
```

I get

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEE72EAD7B (RTDynamics-vc11-md-64.dll) in CGF_flight_controller.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE72EAD7B (RTDynamics-vc11-md-64.dll) in CGF_flight_controller.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.
```

I'm having trouble getting my head around having to explicitly pass by reference as I am normally a Java developer. Please can someone assist me to figure it out?

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's got do with the definition of the class `AssetRepository`. Please post that.

Answer (score 0):

This code is absolutely wrong.

```
AssetRepository& function() {
    [...]
    AssetRepository repository = [...];
    [...]
    return repository; // by reference
    // but "repository" gets destroyed...
}
```

You are returning a reference to an object that doesn't exist after the function returns.  Don't do that.  This is called a "dangling reference" (put that into Google).  You can only use references to objects that exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, AssetRepository&>
```

The value of containers should be [Assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable). but references are not assignable. you can only initialize them once when they are declared, and you cannot make them reference something else later.

But you have some solutions:

- Use values as your working code is doing. and use [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) to reduce cost of copying values.
- Use a pointer to AssetRepository in your map:

  `std::unordered_map<std::string, AssetRepository*>`
- Use [reference wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to make the reference assignable.

For more info and solutions, check this question: [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the end, and incorporated both the comment about a dangling reference and the suggestion to use pointers instead.

```
AssetRepository* AssetRepositoryFactory::getAssetRepository(std::string clientId)
{

    std::unordered_map<std::string, AssetRepository>::iterator iterator = m_repositories.find(clientId);
    if ( iterator != m_repositories.end())
    {
        AssetRepository repository = iterator->second;
        return &(iterator->second);
    }
    else
    {
        AssetRepository repository = AssetRepository(clientId);
        std::pair<std::string, AssetRepository> pair (clientId, repository);
        m_repositories.insert(pair);
        return getAssetRepository(clientId);
    }

}
```