# Connecting three different objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr

I asked a similar question a couple of hours ago about connecting two elements of a vector. Now, I would like to make my question more general. Let's assume that we have two objects of the type double namely `double d1, d2`. We want the third object (`double d3`) to obtain the value of `d1+d2`, such that if we change `d1` or `d2`, then `d3` automatically obtains the new value of `d1+d2`. How can we do it in C++?

This is what I mean:

```
int main(){
double d1,d2,d3;
d1=4;
d2=7;

//some operations to make d3=d1+d2

std::cout<<d3<<endl;// I want it to print 11
d2=-4;
std::cout<<d3<<endl;//Now without any further operations between these line, it should print 0
return 0;     
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Good Question! ...This kind of problem is found in parametric modeling... There's typically a sacrifice between generality and perfomance. Jarod42's answer is good. But for automatic change, it requires a bit of work

Comment: When you say "automatically obtains"  do you want the third object to be notified when one of the first two objects are changed or are you happy with a pull model where you detect changes when you need them?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. @ChrisDrew What I mean is that if I change any of the first two objects, the value assigned to the third object also changes without any further explicit operations.

Comment: @Eman, You can't do it at compile time without some Life-threatening template and Macro tricks. But if you meant from a user level (or at runtime), You may be interested in my answer

Answer (score 11):

You can create a wrapper, as a lambda:

```
double d1 = 0, d2 = 0;
auto l = [&](){ return d1 + d2; };

l(); // 0
d1 = 40;
d2 = 2;
l(); // 42
```

If you want that all the variables has the same type, you may add a type-erasure wrapper as `std::function`:

```
std::function<double()> f1 = [] { return 0; };
std::function<double()> f2 = [] { return 0; };
std::function<double()> sum = [&] { return f1() + f2(); };

std::cout << sum() << std::endl; // 0
f1 = [] { return 40; };
f2 = [] { return 2; };

std::cout << sum() << std::endl; // 42
```

Comment: You should have a look at the OP's [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952849/how-to-connect-two-elements-of-a-vector). A lambda won't really work for that case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the answer. The only problem is that I want the third object to be of the same type as the first two ones, but in this code "l" has a different type than double.

Comment: @Eman Than post more code of how you are expecting to use it. You can't have double which will by itself for "no particular reason"

Comment: @Zereges I added a piece of code to elaborate what I exactly mean by automatic change of the third object.

Comment: @Eman: Some change to make all variable the same type (but not `double`)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks a lot. At least I got an insight from your code as to which direction I might go.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is the classical motivation for parameter binding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//generic add
template <typename T>
void Add(T x, T y, T & z){
  z = x + y;
}

int main(){

  //z will change automatically in function call
  double z = 0;

  //bind z as the result
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  auto add = std::bind(Add<double>, _1, _2, std::ref(z));

  //z is implicity passed and changed
  add(6,4);

  //outputs 10
  std::cout << z << '\n';
}
```

[bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [reference wrappers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) can help achieve the functionality you are after.

Answer (score 7):

Write a wrapper, which will store pointers to `double`s (as recommended in your original question). Beware, that this will not work, if `double`s will go out of scope but `counter` would not. Also, you can overload conversion to `T` operator to get rid of `total()` function.

```
template<typename T>
class counter
{
public:
    void regist(T& d)
    {
        refs.push_back(&d);
    }

    T total()
    {
        T total{};
        for (auto d : refs)
            total += *d;
        return total;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T*> refs;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double d1 = 1.6;
    double d2 = 7.2;
    double d3 = 1e-4;
    counter<double> cnt;
    cnt.regist(d1);
    cnt.regist(d2);
    cnt.regist(d3);
    std::cout << cnt.total() << std::endl; // 8.8001
    d2 = -7.1;
    std::cout << cnt.total() << std::endl; // -5.4999
}
```

Answer (score 5):

At compile time, No, at best, you'll end up with some nasty template and Macro hacks that will still be severely limited. If your thought is on compile-time, don't read the rest of the answer

From a User level (at run time)? Yes, you can. Though, the Logic is quite simple, you are just to find a way to pragmatically create and maintain the invariants of an Expression Tree. It requires a bit of work to get it actualized.

So, Lets, tackle the Logic...
For simplicity, let us define some basic terms here to fit our intent

- An `operator` is a function that requires at most 2 `operands` such that when called, it produces a result which is another `operand`
- An `operand` is an object of interest, in your case, numbers, more precisely `double`. It can be produced by you or an `expression`
- An `expression` is an object that takes at most 2 `operands` and an `operator`, and produces a resulting `operand` by calling the `operator` function.

I did some drawings to illustrate this....

[image: Expression Tree]

As you can see, the arrows shows the direction of knowledge.

- An `Operand` knows all the expressions its involved in.
- An `Expression` knows the `Operands` it produced.

So, Let us give them some identities...

[image: Expression Tree]

Let us say, you created `Operand 1`, `Operand 2`, `Operand 4`. And you started building up this expression tree in this order:

1. You created a relationship (an `Expression`) between `Operand 1` and `Operand 2` which is represented by `Expression1`.
2. `Expression1` uses the `Operator` it was constructed with to produce its result, `Operand 3`
3. You combined the resulting `Operand 3` with your created `Operand 4` into a new expression `Expression2` to produce another result, `Operand 5`

---

Now, let us see what happens when we decide to modify `Operand 1`.

[image: Effect of modifying one Operand]

As you can see, the modified operand will recursively go through and update all subexpressions whose result depends on it (whether directly or by proxy).

---

Now, that we've got this very simple idea, how do we go about it.
There are a number of ways you can implement it, the more generic and flexible it is, the less performant it will likely be (in terms of Memory and Speed)

I did a simple implementation below (Obviously, far from anything Optimal).

```
template<typename T>
class Operand;

template<typename T>
class Expression {
    std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> m_operand1;
    std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> m_operand2;
    std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> m_result;
    T (*m_operator)(const T&, const T&);

    friend class Operand<T>;

    public:
    Expression(
               T(*operator_func)(const T&, const T&),
               std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> operand_1,
               std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> operand_2) :
                   m_operand1(operand_1),
                   m_operand2(operand_2),
                   m_result(std::make_shared<Operand<T>>(T{})),
                   m_operator(operator_func)
    {
    }

    void update(){
        m_result->value() = m_operator(m_operand1->value(), m_operand2->value());
        m_result->update();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>>& result() { return m_result; }

};

template<typename T>
class Operand {
    T val;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Expression<T>>> expressions;
    friend class Expression<T>;

    public:

    Operand(T value) : val(value) {}

    T& value() { return val; }

    void update(){
        for(auto& x : expressions)
            x->update();
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> make(const T& t){
        return std::make_shared<Operand<T>>(t);
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>>
        relate(
               T(*operator_func)(const T&, const T&),
               std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> operand_1,
               std::shared_ptr<Operand<T>> operand_2
               ){
        auto e = std::make_shared<Expression<T>>(operator_func, operand_1, operand_2);
        operand_1->expressions.push_back( e );
        operand_2->expressions.push_back( e );
        e->update();
        return e->result();
    }
};

//template<typename T>
//double add(const double& lhs, const double& rhs){ return lhs + rhs; }

template<typename T>
T add(const T& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs + rhs; }

template<typename T>
T mul(const T& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs * rhs; }

int main()
{
    using DOperand  = Operand<double>;

    auto d1 = DOperand::make(54.64);
    auto d2 = DOperand::make(55.36);

    auto d3 = DOperand::relate(add<double>, d1, d2);
    auto d4 = DOperand::relate(mul<double>, d3, d2);



    //---------------PRINT------------------------//
    std::cout << "d1 = " << d1->value() << "\nd2 = " << d2->value()
              << "\nd3 = d1 + d2 = " << d3->value() << "\nd4 = d3 * d2 = "
              << d4->value() << std::endl;


    //---------------UPDATE ONE VARIABLE------------------------//
    std::cout << "\n\n====================\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "changed d1 from " << d1->value() << " to ";
    d1->value() = -863.2436356;
    d1->update();
    std::cout << d1->value() << "\n\n=======================\n\n";



    //---------------PRINT------------------------//
    std::cout << "d1 = " << d1->value() << "\nd2 = " << d2->value()
              << "\nd3 = d1 + d2 = " << d3->value() << "\nd4 = d3 * d2 = "
              << d4->value() << std::endl;


    // *******************************************
    std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\nSizeof(Operand<int>) = " << sizeof(Operand<int>)
              << "\nSizeof(Expression<int>) = " << sizeof(Expression<int>) << std::endl;
}
```

The Output is:

```
d1 = 54.64
d2 = 55.36
d3 = d1 + d2 = 110
d4 = d3 * d2 = 6089.6

====================
changed d1 from 54.64 to -863.244
=======================

d1 = -863.244
d2 = 55.36
d3 = d1 + d2 = -807.884
d4 = d3 * d2 = -44724.4
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84a18ae7de69d7cc)

For simple `integral` types, my usage of `shared_ptr` was an overkill, I could actually do this with normal pointers. But this implementation tends to generalize on the type of `typename T`.

Other things to think of...

- API choices
- Memory usage
- Avoiding Cycle detection (infinitely recursive updates)
- ...etc

Comments, Criticisms and suggestions are welcomed. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful. Changing the value at run time is sufficient for what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this without changing the type of `d1` and `d2` into something observable. You can do something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class ObservableDouble
{
public:    
    boost::signals2::signal<void()> sigChanged;

    void operator=( double val ) 
    {
        d = val;
        sigChanged();
    }

    operator double() const { return d; } 

private:    
    double d;    
};

int main() 
{
    ObservableDouble d1;
    ObservableDouble d2;        
    double d3;

    auto add = [&](){ d3 = d1 + d2; };

    d1.sigChanged.connect( add );
    d2.sigChanged.connect( add );

    d1 = 4.0;
    d2 = 7.0;        
    std::cout << d3 << std::endl; // prints 11
    d2 = -4.0;
    std::cout << d3 << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

**<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a58f19d2f9a5e4db)</kbd>**

Comment: +1 for signals - when the number of objects observed to make a result is much larger than 2 this approach is much more efficient.