# Container of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Since pointer and reference both achieve the is-a relationship in
context of inheritance in c++.
So as we are used to store container of pointers to object to
achieve polymorphic behavior is it also possible to do it with containers? That is to store references instead of pointers in the container?

My question is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references) because it's in the context of polymorphism

Comment: Pointers are references I think. Can you explain further your requirement? Or give an example?

Comment: instead of having set<Object*> we will have set<Object&> is such thing possible?

Comment: @Elyasin - Pointers are *not* references

Comment: related/dupe [Why can't I make a vector of references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)

Comment: @Smeeheey Maybe you are just riding on a technicality here. But as far as usage in that use case is concerned I think they are same same. Look at the answer below. The reference_wrapper just wraps a pointer. Look at it that way: `int *p` it a pointer declaration, `p` is a reference and `*p` a dereference. There's no need to show off with tightly defined technical terms. I understand what you want to say, but that is not the way I wanted to go, just leave it.

Comment: @Elyasin - The answer below is mine. Oh the irony :)

Comment: Irony on or off. I hope you learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the special class `std::reference_wrapper`, for example:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>> ref_vector;
```

Here is an example use:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2};
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> refs(vec.begin(), vec.end());

vec[1] = 3;
std::copy(refs.begin(), refs.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

The output it "1 3", which demonstrates that references to the original elements are held rather than copies (otherwise the output would have been "1 2").

Comment: Could you, if possible, please provide some examples of use?

Comment: @NathanOliver: quoting from cppreference: "std::reference_wrapper is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like std::vector) which cannot normally hold references."

Comment: @Smeeheey And if you look a little farther down in the "possible implementation" it has `T* _ptr;`.  Just wrapping a reference would not work as references are not copyable and that would make `reference_wrapper` not copyable.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I'm not contradicting you. The OP asked for a way that references could be stored in a container, and I showed him the construct that does this. Yes, its is implemented using pointers. But then again references themselves are implemented using pointers anyway.

Comment: @Smeeheey: References are alias. Whether they are implemented as pointer or not is upto implementer. Pointer have memory location. Reference may or may not have their own dedicated memory location.

Comment: @sameerkn - I know all that. Sigh... Why am I getting dragged off into this? I'm perfectly aware of the conceptual differences between references and pointers. My above implementation provides a *conceptual* container of references, precisely what `std::reference_wrapper` was designed for. The fact that the *implementation* may or may not use pointers (just like the implementation of references may or may not use pointers) is surely not the point!

Comment: @Smeeheey: Am not teaching. I saw a line in your comment *"But then again references themselves are implemented using pointers anyway."*  which seems to be strongly advocating the fact that references are implemented as pointer. Any way that's all off topic :)