# Storing references with std:: containers , gnu c++98

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I came across this comment in another SO post, regarding storing references in a std container:

> It's a flaw in the C++ language. You can't take the address of a
>   reference, since attempting to do so would result in the address of
>   the object being referred to, and thus you can never get a pointer to
>   a reference.  std::vector works with pointers to its elements, so the
>   values being stored need to be able to be pointed to. You'll have to
>   use pointers instead.

The post:

[Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)

Assuming this is correct, can someone explain why my below code works? I'm  not trying to imply the person is wrong, I'm just trying to make sure I understand what's possible and what's not.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "stdio.h"

struct TestStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class TestClass {
public:
TestClass(int x, int y);
int getX();
int getY();
private:
int mX;
int mY;
};

TestClass::TestClass(int x, int y)
{
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

int TestClass::getX()
{
    return mX;
}

int TestClass::getY()
{
    return mY;
}


int main()
{
    // test struct
    std::vector<TestStruct> structVec;

    TestStruct testStruct;
    testStruct.x = 10;
    testStruct.y = 100;
    structVec.push_back(testStruct);
    testStruct.x = 2;
    testStruct.y = 200;
    structVec.push_back(testStruct);
    testStruct.x = 3;
    testStruct.y = 300;
    structVec.push_back(testStruct);

    for (int i = 0; i < structVec.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("testStruct [%d] - [x: %d, y: %d] \n", i, structVec[i].x, structVec[i].y);
    }

    // test object
    std::vector<TestClass> objVec;

    objVec.push_back(*new TestClass(10, 100));
    objVec.push_back(*new TestClass(20, 200));
    objVec.push_back(*new TestClass(30, 300));
    for (int i = 0; i < objVec.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("objVec [%d] - [x: %d, y: %d] \n", i, objVec[i].getX(), objVec[i].getY());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testStruct [0] - [x: 10, y: 100] 
testStruct [1] - [x: 2, y: 200] 
testStruct [2] - [x: 3, y: 300] 
objVec [0] - [x: 10, y: 100] 
objVec [1] - [x: 20, y: 200] 
objVec [2] - [x: 30, y: 300]
```

Comment: You don't have a `vector` of references in your code. You have a memory leak, otoh.

Comment: Since the quote says, in part, "std::vector works with pointers to its elements", which is nonsense, I wouldn't pay any attention to anything else that it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write code like this:

> ```
> objVec.push_back(*new TestClass(10, 100));
> ```

you are creating a `new` instance of `TestClass` on the heap, then you are dereferencing it using `*`, and then this is copied inside the vector when you call `push_back`.

But you are *leaking* the original `TestClass` object allocated using `new` on the heap.

You may want to use a `vector<shared_ptr<TestClass>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<TestClass>>` instead if you want to store pointers (*smart* pointers) instead of `TestClass` instances (are you sure?).

Note that a vector of references would be `vector<TestClass&>`, which is wrong.

**P.S.** As you cited C++98" in the title, you can't have `unique_ptr` as it requires C++11 move semantics. `shared_ptr` became standard with C++11; you can still use `boost::shared_ptr` in C++98.

Comment: Thanks! Your first sentence clears things up for me. Just to be sure I understand correctly, in my above code I would have 3 TestClass objects on the heap and copies of those same 3 TestClass objects also within objVec on the stack, is that correct?

Comment: Three leaked on the heap, and three safely stored in std::vector.