# Why was a change in vector not reflected in a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to vectors.

I have two vectors, `vector1` and `vector2`, both have two values each. Now, using these two vectors, I have made a 2 dimensional vector, `vector_2d` whose value(contents) I want to print. I use the below code and everything works fine.

```
vector<int> vector1;
vector<int> vector2;

vector1.push_back(10);
vector1.push_back(20);

vector2.push_back(100);
vector2.push_back(200);

vector_2d.push_back(vector1);
vector_2d.push_back(vector2);

cout<<"The elements in vector_2d are: "<<vector_2d.at(0).at(0)<<" "<<vector_2d.at(0).at(1)<<" "<<vector_2d.at(1).at(0)<<" "<<vector_2d.at(1).at(1)<<endl;
```

Now, I want to replace the first value in `vector1` (which is 10) with 1000. I do it by a simple assignment operator:

```
vector1.at(0) = 1000;
```

Now, I try to print `vector1` and `vector_2d` again. I get the result that I expected with `vector1`:

```
cout<<vector1.at(0)<<endl; //1000
```

But when I print `vector_2d`, I get the same result as before. The changes done in `vector1` are not being reflected in the 2D vector. Why is this happening?

Comment: When you `push_back` into `vector_2d` you are making a copy. It is not the same as the original.

Comment: @ChrisMM Can you elaborate on that please? What does a "copy" mean in this context? Is it that the compiler is creating a similar vector and and using it to `push_back` into the `vector_2d`? If so, then how can I make sure that both these vectors are in sync with each other, and the value changes (if any) are reflected throughout the code?

Comment: You can try instead: `vector_2d.push_back(vector<int>()); vector_2d.back().push_back(10); // or vector_2d[0].push_back(10);`.

Comment: Internally, it is a bit more complex, but a copy of a vector is as much a copy as a copy of an int is: `int x = 10, int y = x; y = 12;` won't modify `x` either...

Comment: If you *promise* that the two single vectors live at least as long as the 2d vector, you could place them in a vector of pointers or references (you'll need `std::reference_wrapper` then). If you don't keep the promise, you'll end up with dangling pointers or references, so a potentially dangerous approach.

Comment: @Aconcagua That makes sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Scheff So how exactly is that going to keep the two vectors in sync? If I understand your code correctly, I am pushing value "10" to the first index of `vector_2d`.

Comment: Well. The first element of `vector_2d` is of type `vector<int>`. Hence, `push_back()` can be applied. There is no option to _keep the two vectors in sync_. For that, you had to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>&>`... (but I wouldn't recommend this.) However, I once wrote an answer which might be of interest: [SO: vector of existing objests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039844/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff Ahhhh right... sounds a bit like "vector-ception" :P Thanks btw, this helps.

Comment: @Scheff `std::vector<T&>` is invalid for all `T`. You probably mean `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>>`

Comment: @Caleth You are correct (and my comment a bit sloppy). Actually, what you proposed is just what I did in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in your 2D vector is not changed, because while pushing back 1D vectors

```
vector_2d.push_back(vector1);
vector_2d.push_back(vector2);
```

you made copies of each of them. Therefore, changing values in `vector1` will not change the values in its copy stored as element 0 of `vector_2d`. If you would like to change the values in 2D vector, you can do it directly:

```
vector_2d.at(0).at(0) = 0;
```

Another possibilities were mentioned in the comments to your question (like having a vector of pointers or references), but I do not recommend those because of possible memory violations (e.g. if your 2D vector will live longer than 1D vectors that are referenced).