# How do I push vectors by reference?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

This code below doesn't work because I push_back the vectors a and b to the vector vector and then alter the vectors a and b. I want to alter the vectors a and b so that the vector vector suffers the same modifications. How do I do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
std::vector<std::vector<int>>vector;
std::vector<int>a;
std::vector<int>b;
vector.push_back(a);
vector.push_back(b);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    a.push_back(i);
for (int i = 11; i <= 20; i++)
    b.push_back(i);
std::cout << vector[1][0];
std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Work with the vector directly - e.g. `vector[0].push_back(i)` in the first loop rather than `a.push_back(i)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `v` (`vector` is not a good name since it shares with the library and makes the code confusing) to be a `vector` of `vector` pointers (since [a vector of references is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> v; //declare as vec of vec pointers
...
v.push_back(&a); //push_back addresses of a and b
v.push_back(&b);
...
std::cout << v.at(1)->at(0) //dereference and call at on the inner vec
```

---

Note that this can be dangerous if `a` or `b` go out of scope before `v`, as that will leave you with dangling pointers, a mess of undefined behavior and a murder time-consuming bugs.

Comment: This is dangerous if the vector (or a copy of it) outlives `a` or `b`, since it will contain dangling references.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) (since C++11).

> `std::reference_wrapper` is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like `std::vector`) which cannot normally hold references.

e.g.

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>> v;
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
v.push_back(a);
v.push_back(b);
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    a.push_back(i);
for (int i = 11; i <= 20; i++)
    b.push_back(i);
std::cout << v[1].get()[0]; //11
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q9TRiy6GKeDeslAF)

Note that if the `vector` has longer timelife than `a` and `b`, then when `a` and `b` get destroyed the references stored in the `vector` become dangled.

Comment: One problem here is that `v` contains references to `a` and `b` after they go out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that `push_back` *copies* its parameter to the end of the vector. To modify the object in the vector, you need to get a reference to it. One approach:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > my_vector;
my_vector.reserve(2);  // Going over the allocation invalidates references

my_vector.push_back( std::vector<int>() );
std::vector<int> & a = my_vector.back();

my_vector.push_back( std::vector<int>() );
std::vector<int> & b = my_vector.back();
```

(I changed the name of the variable because using "vector" as a variable name tends to lead to confusion.)

If you can use C++17, there is a way to reduce the lines of code using `emplace_back`.

Comment: `emplace_back` exists in C++11 and C++14 as well.

Comment: @Matt true, but before C++17, its return type was `void`.

Comment: Just be careful, because if the second `push_back` grows the vector's capacity, the reference obtained from the earlier `back()` will become invalid.

Comment: @JaMiT very true, I didn't see where you were going but now it's clear.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point. I've added a reservation to avoid that. And I admit there are probably better ways to do things; it's just tough to pick one without seeing the larger picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of vectors ahead of time you can do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(2);
std::vector<int> &a = v[0];
std::vector<int> &b = v[1];
...
```