# Smart pointers (unique pointers) and references

Tags: c++, binding, data-management

In my code I have a static class to store objects. To do stuff with inherence (casting etc) I store the objects in a map with `unique_ptr`s.

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<DummyClass>>Map;
```

The stored objects have some member variables I want to update in my code (via variable bindings) so I pass out a reference to the stored objects to being able to modify them.

```
DummyClass& GetObject(std::string name)
{
  return *Map[name];
}
```

To update the members I store them in another map, in another class, to bind them to a string (I get the values via TCP/IP), something like this:

```
updater->registerVariable("bindingString", dummyObject.position.x);
```

The `registerVariable` Method also takes a reference (to `dummyObject.position.x`) and stores it in it's map.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<float&>> floatBindings;
```

But here raises the problem: I can't store references in the bindings map.

Anyone has a good idea what I could do instead? Would `shared_ptr`s the way to go? But the thing is that I don't really want do use `shared_ptr` s because the owner should only be the static class.

Comment: Good old fashioned, non-owning, raw pointers? Or [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)?

Comment: You can also store `std::shared_ptr` and return `std::weak_ptr`. This way Map mostly retains ownership and you can check if the pointer has been deleted before using it in `floatBindings`.

Comment: First figure your chain of ownership out: who owns those objects? Who's allowed to either share ownership (`std::shared_ptr`) or just access the object if it hasn't been deleted yet (`std::weak_ptr`)?

Comment: Will the element in your *map* always live longer than the parts that use the reference to it?

Comment: @Galik yes, the elements in the map will always be deleted last.
Thank you guys for the answers so far!

Comment: Note that your `GetObject()` will fail miserably if the specified `name` does not exist in the `map`. `Map[name]` will return a default-constructed `unique_ptr` holding a `nullptr`, and then `operator*` will have *undefined behavior*. If `name` doesn't exist, you should either raise an exception, or else create a default object to return a reference to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau one can always check the string exists as a key in the map right ?! you can use reference_wrapper I have had good experiences with it !

Comment: @AdityaG yes, the `name` can be  checked for existance, by using `std::map::find()`, but the function would still need to decide what it should do/return in that situation

Comment: Thanks for advide, I do check the map content, don't worry. Just tried to ceep  it small.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/922455/8894272

> The component type of containers like vectors must be assignable.
> References are not assignable (you can only initialize them once when
> they are declared, and you cannot make them reference something else
> later). Other non-assignable types are also not allowed as components
> of containers, e.g. vector is not allowed.

This is basically the same since I tried to store a vector of references (in a map).