# Passing arbitrary number of parameters using vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm dealing with C++ objects that use destructor to deallocate resources. When passing those objects to a function with an arbitrary number of parameters.
Is there any way to get rid of using pointers in this case?

One possible solution is passing a vector of pointers to those objects.
if I pass the objects themselves, the destructors will be called twice, one is the real objects, another is when the vector is deallocated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
class integer {
    private:
        int data;
    public:
        integer(int value = 0): data(value) {}
        ~integer() {}
        void increase() {
            data++;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& x);
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& x) {
    os << x.data;
    return os;
}
void foo(std::vector<integer*> vec) {
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->increase();
    }
}
int main() {
    integer x1(3);
    integer x2(4);
    integer x3(5);

    std::cout << x1 << " " << x2 << " " << x3 << std::endl;

    foo({&x1, &x2, &x3});

    std::cout << x1 << " " << x2 << " " << x3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected results:

```
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

Comment: No, the destructor of `vector` calls the destructor of `integer*`, which is a no-op and does not call the destructor of `integer`.

Comment: `the deconstructors will be called twice, one is the real objects, another is when the vector is deallocated.` That is not entirely true, because those objects will be copied, so there are two copies of each and both have to be deallocated.

Comment: The code shown above matches the requirement. The actual question is how to get rid of using pointers. Thanks

Comment: Why would you use pointers in the first place?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with pointers? That's exactly the ownership you want.

Comment: @Quimby Why not passing the vector as a reference: `void foo(std::vector<integer*> vec)` to `void foo(std::vector<integer>& vec)`?

Comment: @Quimby Since C++ provides references, it might be a better approach to not to use pointers.

Comment: @Timo Because then it would not increment the integers `x1, x2, x3` in main.

Comment: @Timo I've tested this, the compiler will create a vector of integer objects, that calls copy constructor and finally calls destructor.

Comment: Ha, joke's on me. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Timo It happens :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)

Comment: @jaket Oh, yes, It's duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with pointers, but of course you can avoid pointers with `reference_wrapper`s. (Don't forget to `#include <functional>`)

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<integer>>& vec)
{
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        (*it)->increase();
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like `foo({x1, x2, x3})`.

[<kbd>live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8OJD1kfhSBB30X55)

---

You can even get rid of the `{}` if you want:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&... args)
{
    static_assert(std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<Args, integer>...>);
    (args.increase(), ...);
}
```

(Don't forget to `#include <type_traits>`.)
Now you can call it like `foo(x1, x2, x3)`.

Comment: I've tried the live demo, does `std::reference_wrapper<type>` work only on Clang compiler? gcc gives errors.

Comment: @NgọcKhánhNguyễn My bad! I forgot to `#include <functional>`. I have updated the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterators. Once you have more than 3 you should not continue with `x4` but use a containter anyhow. Your `foo` would be

```
template <typename iterator_t>
void foo(iterator_t begin,iterator_t end) {
    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) begin->increase();
}
```

And in `main`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<integer> x { {3},{4},{5} };
    for (const auto& i : x) std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    foo(x.begin(),x.end());
    for (const auto& i : x) std::cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```