# How to fix 'reference to type requires an initializer'?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I am working on implementing LRU Cache based on a LeetCode exercise, but the following code does not compile

```cpp
using namespace std;

class LRUCache {
private:
    list<int> data;
    unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator&> keys_to_data;

    void update_recency(int key, list<int>::iterator& it) {
        data.erase(it);
        data.push_front(key);
        keys_to_data[key]; // issue here
    }
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity) {

    }

    int get(int key) {
        int value = -1;
        auto value_it = keys_to_data.find(key);
        if(value_it != keys_to_data.end()) {
            value = *(value_it->second);
            update_recency(key, value_it->second);
        }
        return value;
    }

    void put(int key, int value) {
    }
};
```

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1360:7: error: reference to type 'std::__1::__list_iterator' requires an initializer
      second(_VSTD::forward<_Args2>(_VSTD::get<_I2>(__second_args))...)
      ^

... huge stacktrace ...

/Users/Paul/Desktop/int/main.cpp:17:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unordered_map &, std::__1::hash, std::__1::equal_to, std::__1::allocator &> > >::operator[]' requested here
        keys_to_data[key];

Comment: Could you share your reasoning as to why you need a reference to an iterator in `unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator&>`?

Comment: (In case it's not clear: You cannot use references as a map value.)

Comment: Possible answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot store a reference as value in your map

```
unordered_map<int, list<int>::iterator&>
```

As the reference is not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

Storage the iterator, not a reference to the iterator

unordered_map::iterator> keys_to_data;