# Returning reference to private members inside a template class

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class testTemp {
    std::vector<T> container;
public:
    std::vector<T&> getTest(int nrOfEle);
    void push(T row){container.push_back(row);}
};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T&> testTemp<T>::getTest(int nrOfEle) {
    std::vector<T&> refContainer;
    for(int i =0; i < nrOfEle; i++){
        refContainer.push_back(container[i]);
    }
    return refContainer;
}


int main() {
    testTemp<std::vector<int> > test; // T =std::vector<std::int>
    std::vector<int> fillMeUp;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        fillMeUp.push_back(i);
    }

    test.push(fillMeUp);
    std::vector<int> container = test.getTest(3); // when i change the elements in container
    container[0] = 999; //this change should also affect the private `member inside the testTemp class`

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to be able to do, is from main call the function getTest() with the number of elements I want to change. In the code above I want to change the 3 first elements. So I input that into the function. The function should then return a container to main containing the 3 first elements of the private member std::vector container as references so that when i make a change in main it also changes the element in the class container     std::vector container. I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. The code above is my first attempt but it results in an error

```
 "/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:63:26: error: forming pointer
 to reference type ‘std::vector<int>&’    63 |       typedef _Tp*      
 pointer;"
```

after reading the comment by formerlyknownas_463035818 i've changed to

```
   template<typename T>
      T* testTemp<T>::getTest(int nrOfEle) {

      return &container[nrOfEle];
      }
```

however this seems to return the address of the vector object rather than the element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `std::vector` of references. There is `std::reference_wrapper`, but I would suggest a different design. Instead of returning a new vector, I would rather return a `begin` and `end` (3rd element) iterator. Those iterators can be coming directly from the private member. If you are worried about the caller modifiying elements beyond the 3rd you could write a wrapper for the iterator that only provides access to the first three elements.

Something along the line of:

```
template <typename T> class testTemp {
    std::vector<T> container;
public:
    std::vector<T>::iterator getTest_begin() { return container.begin(); }
    std::vector<T>::iterator getTetst_end(int nrOfEle) { return container.begin() + nrOfEle; }
    void push(T row){container.push_back(row);}
};
```

Of course you should make sure that the `container` actually does contain enough elements.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to return the address to a specific element with templates. I edited my question with the new code after reading your answer.
 but this seems to get me the address to the vector rather than the element

Comment: @Freebi32 I didnt mention pointers anywhere.... I edited to make it more clear

Comment: @Freebi32 btw "however this seems to return the address of the vector object rather than the element" no it doesnt. The code you posted returns a pointer to an element in the vector