# How should I implement a temporarily child object of an existing parent?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

I know the question is going to sound weird, so let me start of with the issues:

### Problem 1

I'm making a Monopoly game (for which a `Monopoly` class has been made that has a `PlayerList` member, containing players), and I had implemented an `Auction` class. I recently discovered that I have a lot of comparable code in the `Auction` class and the `PlayerList` class, so I put a lot of `Auction`-code in the `BidderList` class.

```cpp
// Auction.cpp
Auction::Auction(Property* property, PlayerList* bidderList, int currBidderIndex)
    : m_property{ property }, m_bidderList{ new BidderList(bidderList, currBidderIndex) },
    m_highestBid{ startBid }, m_previous_has_left{ false }
{
}

// BidderList.cpp
BidderList::BidderList(PlayerList* playerList, int currBidderIndex)
    : PlayerList(playerList)
{
    m_currPlayerIndex = currBidderIndex;
}
```

However... in my implementation of an Auction, it's used as a temporary object that will be destroyed after it's done. (Yes, I *could* give it setters.) Since I'm using the original player objects (which is needed to modify them), I'm also deleting those in the base destructor (unintentionally) when the `BidderList` object gets destroyed:

```cpp
PlayerList::~PlayerList()
{
    for (const auto player : m_players)
        delete player;
}
```

... which forced me to do something like this:

```cpp
// Prevent base class from deleting the players! - not so clean
BidderList::~BidderList()
{
    int size = getSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        m_players[i] = nullptr;
}
```

I still want to use my players after the Auction, since it's not sure the game will have ended. I was wondering if I could do this on a cleaner way.

### Problem 2

I was also thinking about making deriving `Bidder` and (`Trader` for `Trade`) from the Player class (which doesn't solve the previous problem in any obvious way), because this way I could again achieve higher cohesion. Although the problem isn't big in this situation, I still would like to know an answer to the following problem:

Somehow, each player *acts* as a bidder in during an Auction (which is still temporary).

- I can copy each player into a bidder, but then I won't be modifying the actual player (which I want, of course).
- I can make the Bidder in such a way that it contains a pointer to the actual object, that would mean I have to relink every method of the Player to the bidder, where I should actually be using inheritance.

If I somehow manage to convert the actual player to a bidder (so I would be using the original player object), then I still have to make sure only the derived class is destroyed - sounds like since fiction to me. Is there no other way around then using the composite relation here? Because, it would look like this and it ain't pretty:

```cpp
bool Derived::foo()
{
    return m_base.foo();
}
```

In both problems, I have a need for a temporary derived class, constructed with an existing parent, which needs to be cleaned up afterwards in a safe way. Could you please help me with making the right decision here? (Yes, I *do* want to keep the Auction object a temporary object, just for practice). Thanks in advance!

Comment: A list of referenced to chickens and a list of chickens are related in that read-only access can be done on both.  But I suspect the glue code is going to be bigger than the duplicate codebifbyou implement them seperately.  Your bit about destroying derived classes is nonsense; C++ does not work that way.

Comment: You can make `m_players` a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Player>>` if you want a `PlayerList` to *share* ownership of `Players` between different `PlayerList`s (such as your master player list and your bidder list).

Comment: @Yakk, I know that is not possible, that's why I'm asking if such has to be done using composition

Comment: @John, that's actually not a bad idea at all! Thanks, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Another option is to scrap `BidderList` entirely and just have a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Player>> bidders`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Comment: That's probably safe. Even if a bankrupted player is removed from the main list (invalidating references to players in the list), any unfortunate player is unlikely to be removed during the auction.

Comment: Hey, I've thought about it the abstract problem (one child becoming another temporary child) and gave an example of how I would handle such problem now. I would like to know what you guys think of it. See the answer to problem 2 below. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought about using `std::shared_ptr<Object>` for a while, and I think I have found the solution to the second problem, although it still has the little downside that *every* member that needs to be modified in child classes, has to be a `shared_ptr`, even when you wouldn't make it a pointer. See the code below, representing classes for employees going on holidays.

## Person

```cpp
/* - - - - - - - HEADER- - - - - - - -*/
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, int capital = 1000);
    std::string getName() const;
    virtual void print() const = 0;
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    std::shared_ptr<int> m_capital;
};

/* - - - - - - - SOURCE- - - - - - - -*/
#include "Person.h"

#include <iostream>

Person::Person(std::string name, int capital)
    : m_name{ name }, m_capital{ std::shared_ptr<int>(new int{capital}) }
{
}

std::string Person::getName() const
{
    return m_name;
}
```

## Employee

```cpp
/* - - - - - - - HEADER- - - - - - - -*/
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"

class Employee : public Person
{
public:
    Employee(std::string name, std::string workName);
    std::string getWorkName() const;
    void print() const override;
private:
    std::string m_workName;
};

/* - - - - - - - SOURCE- - - - - - - -*/
#include "Employee.h"

#include <iostream>

Employee::Employee(std::string name, std::string workName)
    : Person(name), m_workName{ workName }
{
}

std::string Employee::getWorkName() const
{
    return m_workName;
}

void Employee::print() const
{
    std::cout
        << m_name << '\n'
        << "  I'm an employee at " << m_workName << '\n'
        << "  I have a capital of " << std::to_string(*m_capital) << '\n'
        ;
}
```

## Tourist

```cpp
/* - - - - - - - HEADER- - - - - - - -*/
#pragma once
#include "Person.h"
#include <queue>

class Tourist : public Person
{
public:
    Tourist(std::string name, std::queue<std::string> destinations);
    Tourist(const Person& person, std::queue<std::string> destinations);
    void visitNextDestination();
    void print() const override;
private:
    std::queue<std::string> m_destinations;
};

/* - - - - - - - SOURCE- - - - - - - -*/
#include "Tourist.h"

#include <iostream>

Tourist::Tourist(std::string name, std::queue<std::string> destinations)
    : Person(name), m_destinations{destinations}
{
}

Tourist::Tourist(const Person& person, std::queue<std::string> destinations)
    : Person(person), m_destinations{destinations}
{
}

void Tourist::visitNextDestination()
{
    if (m_destinations.size() > 0) {
        m_destinations.pop();
        *m_capital -= 100;
    }
}

void Tourist::print() const
{
    std::cout
        << m_name << '\n'
        << "  I'm a tourist heading for " << m_destinations.front() << '\n'
        << "  I have a capital of " << std::to_string(*m_capital) << '\n'
        ;
}
```

## Main.cpp

```cpp
#include "Employee.h"
#include "Tourist.h"

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::string> destinations;
    destinations.push("Paris");
    destinations.push("London");
    destinations.push("Berlin");

    std::vector<Person*> persons{
        new Employee{"Harry", "Microsoft"},
        new Employee{"Frank", "Apple"},
        new Tourist{"Bob", destinations}
    };

    for (const auto person : persons)
        person->print();

    Tourist* frank = new Tourist{ *persons[1], destinations };
    frank->visitNextDestination();
    frank->print();

    delete frank;
    persons[1]->print();
}
```

## Output

```
Harry
  I'm an employee at Microsoft
  I have a capital of 1000
Frank
  I'm an employee at Apple
  I have a capital of 1000
Bob
  I'm a tourist heading for Paris
  I have a capital of 1000
Frank
  I'm a tourist heading for London
  I have a capital of 900
Frank
  I'm an employee at Apple
  I have a capital of 900
```

Comment: Ehmm. woops, I forgot to clean whatever is written in main.cpp. Seems like I should have used the `unique_ptr`s once again.