# c++, what happens when an lvalue is passed to T&&?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>


template <typename T>
void g(T&& val)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
}

int main()
{
    // g(2);

    int i;
    g(i);
}
```

When g(2) is called, it complies, but when g(i) is called, the complier has a lot of errors.

Some of the errors are pasted as follows:

```
forming pointer to reference type ‘int&’

no members matching ‘std::vector<int&, std::allocator<int&> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<int&, std::allocator<int&> >}::_M_allocate’ in ‘std::vector<int&, std::allocator<int&> >::_Base’ {aka ‘struct std::_Vector_base<int&, std::allocator<int&> >’}

no members matching ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int&>, int&>::_Base_type {aka std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int&> >}::allocate’ in ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int&>, int&>::_Base_type’ {aka ‘struct std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int&> >’}

forming pointer to reference type ‘int&’
```

**my question:**

**1. In this case, when the literal value 2 is called, what type is derived for T ?**

**2. Why doesn't it complie when on i ? How to understand these error messages ?**

Comment: Because you can't have a vector of references.

Comment: It's called a "forwarding reference" or a "universal reference". Look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: A forwarding reference, and

- `g(2)` makes `T` an `int`
- `g(i)` makes `T` an `int&`

2: You can't have arrays of references (`new T&[x]`). You could use `std::remove_cvref_t` to get the type `int` out of `T`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void g(T&& val) {
    using type = std::remove_cvref_t<T>; // type is int

    std::vector<type> v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your universal reference resolves to `int` for `g(2)` and `int&` for `g(i)`
2. You can't have a `std::vector` of a reference type ([see this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references)).