# Taking ownership of an r-value reference

Tags: c++

My goal is to take ownership of the temporary object created with `Derived()` in `main()` with `BaseHolder`.

I'm getting an error at `m_bases.push_back(base)` because it invokes `Base::Base()` which is illegal because it's a purely virtual class, but I don't understand why it's invoked in the first place because my thinking is that the already constructed object would just be moved into `m_bases`.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

```cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class BaseHolder {
    vector<Base> m_bases;
public:
    void add(Base&& base) {
        m_bases.push_back(base);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() override {}
};

int main() {
    BaseHolder base_holder;
    base_holder.add(Derived());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware: Even if `Base` were *not* pure virtual, `vector<Base>` would still be a bad idea because it [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/3282436) objects of type `Derived`.

Comment: @0x5453 Noted, that would be pretty bad.

Comment: I think the only way to work around this is to allocate `Derived()` on the heap and hold onto something like `vector<unique_ptr<Base>>` inside of `BaseHolder`.  Alternatively you could ditch `Base` entirely and template `BaseHolder` on the derived type, but then you would not be able to mix derived types within a single `BaseHolder`.

Comment: I'd be ok allocating `Derived` on the stack and using `vector<Base&> m_bases` instead, but I'm getting `error: forming pointer to reference type ‘Base&’` on that line when I try that.

Comment: you can't make a vector of references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Comment: If you want a vector of references, you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).  But note that that will *not* take ownership of the `Derived` object.