# Passing c++ map by reference and see changes after insert

Tags: c++, reference

**Hey guys!**

I'm just getting into c++ and after learning stuff about reference and value pass I've come across a problem.

So basically I'm trying to copy a map and I do so in my method. So far the size of the 2 maps are the same.

The problem comes when I insert some new values into the original map because it doesn't change the copied map.

So my question is how do I copy/pass a map, with the new map being a real copy and when the original changes, the copied version does so.

I'll attach the code that I was working on.

**The code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> passMapByReference(map<string, int>& temp_map){
 return temp_map;   
}

void printMap(map<string, int>& temp_map ){
    cout << temp_map.size() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    map<string, int> copyMap;
    
    map<string, int> map;
    map["asd"] = 1;
    map["dsa"] = 2;
    
    printMap(map);

    copyMap = passMapByReference(map);
    
    printMap(copyMap);
    
    map["ksdbj"] = 3;
    map["askdnijabsd"] = 4;
    
    printMap(map);
    
    //this should print 4
    printMap(copyMap);
    

    return 0;
}
```

**The output:**

```
2
2
4
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` and `copyMap` are separate objects and so changing one won't affect other. Moreover, you're returning the map **by value** from the function `passMapByReference`. Instead you could return the map **by reference** from `passMapByReference` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

//------------------------v------->return by reference
std::map<std::string, int>& passMapByReference(std::map<std::string, int>& temp_map){
 return temp_map;   
}

void printMap(std::map<std::string, int>& temp_map ){
    std::cout << temp_map.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{  
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    map["asd"] = 1;
    map["dsa"] = 2;
    
    printMap(map);

    //copyMap is an lvalue reference to passMapByReference
    std::map<std::string, int>& copyMap = passMapByReference(map);
    
    printMap(copyMap);
    
    map["ksdbj"] = 3;
    map["askdnijabsd"] = 4;
    
    printMap(map);
    
    printMap(copyMap);//prints 4
    

}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/R49x0U4i5)

The output of the above program is:

```
2
2
4
4
```

##### Note

I noticed that you have used `using namespace std;` and then created a `map` with the name `map`. This should be avoided as it creates confusion. For example, it becomes hard to see whether the `map` you're referring to is a `std::map` or the variable named `map`. I would recommend using `std::` to qualify the standard contianers instead of using `using namespace std;`.

Refer to [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thank you very much!! 
Yes I forgot to remove using namespace.

Basically I get the same result in my code if I write std::map<std::string, int>& copyMap = map;

So the function is basically useless..

Comment: One last question. The whole reason I wanted to create the copy array is because I want to create an array of maps in the same way. How do I do that? So far I had std::map<std::string, int>* data_ = new ...; So in this case if I want to store references how should I declare it?

Comment: @SuperBlaze We cannot store references in an array(or a vector etc). You can store pointers in an array(or a vector etc) though. If you do decide to store pointers that point to dynamically allocated memory then consider using smart pointers so that you won't have to use `new` and `delete` manually. You can also refer to [Why can't I make a vector of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references). Feel free to ask a separate follow up question so that you can describe your case there in more detail than here in comments.

Comment: Thank you again! I'll ask a separate question then!